# Single malloc call for multiple data structures

Tags: c, struct, malloc, heap-memory

Given the following structure:

```c
struct myStructure {
    float                  myField;
};

struct mySecondStructure {
    int                    myField;
    struct myStructure     *mySecondField;
};
```

How can I efficiently allocate the struct `mySecondStructure` on the heap? (With the variable `mySecondField` initialized to a valid memory address)

I came up with two ways doing this:

**First approach**: use two calls to malloc:

```c
struct mySecondStructure *structure = malloc(sizeof(* structure));
structure->mySecondField            = malloc(sizeof(* structure->mySecondField));
```

**Second approach**: use one call to malloc with enough space for both structures:

```c
struct mySecondStructure *structure = malloc(sizeof(struct myStructure) + sizeof(struct mySecondStructure));
structure->mySecondField            = (struct myStructure *)(((unsigned char *)structure) + sizeof(struct mySecondStructure)); // the pointer points now to the end of the first structure
```

But the first one is in my opinion inefficient since it uses two calls to malloc. However I'm not sure if the second one will work properly because of data alignment.

Can someone enlighten me about this?

I'm thankful for any given help.

Comment: Do you *have* to have a pointer to `myStructure` in `mySecondStructure`? It would be so much simpler if `mySecondField` wasn't a pointer. Especially if you always allocate them in pairs like shown in the question.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg See my comment to Rob's entry why I'm using a pointer.

Comment: How about one or more set of flags (or a bitfield) to see what parts of the structure(s) are valid? Have been used successfully in big systems before (like e.g. Windows).

Comment: But then I would need to allocate the struct, whether its used or not.

Comment: And are you running on a system with tight memory requirements? Yes I know, don't bloat and all that, but these days it's hardly worth the effort of saving couple of bytes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Of course, but for me, its a waste of memory.

Answer (score 2):

The second approach should work; structs are padded so that they align properly (for example, consider if you had an array of them).  One downside to the second approach would be if you wanted to reclaim the second structure (there is a reason its not just embedded in the first structure, I presume).

But the first is a lot cleaner, and what benefits there are to the second are minimal at best.

Comment: I think the second approach can also be simplified as `structure->mySecondField = (struct myStructure *)(structure + 1);` which is a bit more readable. Sill I agree with the disadvantages.

Comment: Are there no alignment issues with this?

Comment: @d3l see [Data Structure Padding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1539217/33499) for examples how the compiler can add padding to avoid performance degradation. But even if padding is wrong, it would still work.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect.  The alignment requirement for a struct is that of the member with the largest alignment requirement.  `struct A { char c; };` and `struct B { double d; };` would probably lead to trouble with the second approach.

Answer (score 2):

Both your approaches would work.

The difference between one malloc() call and two depends on how malloc() itself is implemented - which varies between implementations, is affected by operating system and hardware characteristics.

Without measuring the difference for your implementation, in the context of your program, and a typical execution environment (operating system, hardware, etc) all you are doing is indulging in premature optimisation.

Generally speaking, it would be better to do things in a way that are easier to understand (less complex code), easier to get right, and therefore easier to maintain.   Then, if performance is a concern, do measurements to work out the bottlenecks.

In practice, you might also want to consider having a `struct myStructure` within your s`truct mySecondStructure`, rather than a pointer [which is what Joachim's comment is about].   That way, you can allocate with a single malloc() call, without any need for additional bookkeeping to initialise pointers.    Simpler to implement, easier to understand, and - if number of malloc() calls really matters - minimises that number.

Comment: The thing with the pointer is, it comes very handy with the following situation: http://pastie.org/9876255 , if the instance should be threadsafe `threadSafeImpl` is set to a valid memory address, if not, it is set to `NULL`. Then you can simply test for thread safety like this: `if (var->threadSafeImpl) {` and then use the variables appropriately.

Comment: There are many circumstances in which pointers are appropriate.  That's why I said to consider having a struct as a member, rather than simply saying to do it.     However, there is more to achieving thread safety than testing if a pointer is NULL or not.

Comment: The second approach may not work if the alignment requirement for `myStructure` is smaller than that for `mySecondStructure`.

Comment: @Rob I think you did not fully understand me: its not only for testing but for  using these variables. (For example: a thread safe implementation might need a mutex)

Comment: @Oliver:  that is addressed by placing the larger struct first in the allocated memory, since sizeof() will include provision for padding to ensure alignment of the larger struct.

Comment: @Rob - It's not the size of the struct that matters, it's the member with the largest alignment requirement that dictates things.

Comment: @Oliver.  The alignment requirements of every struct type are determined by the alignment needs of its members (with padding ensuring alignment of each member).  sizeof() takes padding into account and malloc() is guaranteed to return a value aligned for any type.  One of the consequences of this is that using sizeof() as described is sufficient to align structs.   It's a bit more involved if padding is disabled (or packing enabled) but that is not the case here.

Comment: It's sufficient so long as the alignment requirements for the first struct are at least as large as those for the second.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the members of the structures, it's possible that they have different alignment requirements. With C11, these requirements can be inspected with `_Alignof` (also related: `_Alignas`, `max_align_t`, `<stdalign.h>`).

A portable solution (also for C99) would be to add padding manually, something along the following:

```
struct mySecondStructure *structure;
size_t secondAlign  = sizeof *structure->mySecondField;
size_t offset       = (sizeof *structure + secondAlign - 1) / secondAlign
                      * secondAlign;
size_t total        = offset + sizeof *structure->mySecondField;
structure                   = malloc(total);
structure->mySecondField    = (void *)((char *)structure + offset);
```

With C11,

```
size_t secondAlign = _Alignof(struct myStructure);
```

also yields a valid (possibly smaller) result.

Otherwise, I agree with the others' comments and answers that this looks like premature optimization. What perhaps could be done now, however, is thinking about how changes in the allocation strategy may influence other peaces of the code and trying to keep such inter-dependencies to a minimum in order to allow later changes if this turns out to be worth it (e.g. if it should be possible to partially release memory, as covered in [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28252494)).